# Shell Command that Combines chmod and chgrp

Tags: linux, unix, chmod, system-calls

Is there a combined variant for `chmod` and `chgrp` that sets both user and groups permissions in one single system call for each file? This is useful for increasing performance on slow data layers such as NFS.

Comment: I would think that the caching component of NFS would mitigate this... or are you using synchronous NFS? Have you timed this as being an issue? You might find that the structure if your directories, and the access patterns (locking overhead) are more significant. For experimentation, you might find http://humbledown.org/nfs-lock-analysis-with-tshark-and-python.xhtml useful (it will move soonish). You might also look at filescached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chgrp doesn't set group permissions, it sets the group itself. Note that chgrp is not a system call; the system call is chown which sets both the owner and group in one go.

Anyway: no, there isn't. The kernel has a system call for chmod and a separate system call for chown.